# Inflation, getView, arrayAdapaters and everything between them

Tags: android, android-layout

I think I have litte theory confuse. if anyone could set it right for me.

Inflation - I would use this technic in order to use dynamic UI. for example I have two xml's main.xml and button.xml. If I want to add button.xml to my main xml. I need to use inflation.

ArrayAdapters - I would use it in order to populate my lists with data.
but sometimes you could use:

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                    R.layout.row, R.id.textview,
                                            items));
```

with no need of inflation or overriding the @getView method. in other hand I guess that will limit you in other cases ? (which cases?)

the above code is also doing some kind of custom list view (row and textview). so who need all the rest?

overriding the getView method - I saw many examples when developers mixing inflation inside the @getView method. I have also seen inflation outside the getView method.. what's the purpose of each option??

If anyone could clear this idea to me. that would be great. I do know those 3 topics concerned about custom lists.

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0):

I think you´re trying to set up a `ListView` right?

You easily can to this by the default array adapter, you posted the suiting code in you question.

If you want to create your custom `ListView` with your custom `ArrayAdapter` you have to override `ArrayAdapter`. Here you can override the `getView`-method.

Usually you define the `View` you want to pass in an XML Layout file. In your `Adapter` you just want to adopt it to match the data. To get the `View` into your Java code, you use `LayoutInflator`. Having the inflated `View` you can easily change and return it.

I hope this helps,
Jonathan

Comment: "you have to override ArrayAdapter. Here you can override the getView-method" So I must override the getView method when I am overriding the ArrayAdapter? could you give me example of wanting to override the ArrayAdapter/getView? after all in my example I am also doing kind of custom Listview.(row and textview)